# Regular Expression of URL

Tags: regex, expression

What is the use of regular Expression `(/.+?/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]_[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])(/.*)?$`  ?

Comment: To match specific texts, I believe. Have you got any trouble using it?

Comment: I could see it in my code but i am not able to understand why it was used by the previous developer ?

Comment: Paste it into the regex field at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) and read the explanation on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically matches strings with /ab_cd in them, where a, b, c and d are any character in upper- or lowercase.

Before that part there must be a slash somewhere with at least one character inbetween.

After that part the string must end or there must be a slash and the string may continue.

Examples of matching Strings are:

- bla/bla/xx_xx
- /bla/xx_xx
- /bla/xx_xx/bla